# How to add a folder in the header and how does .a works?

Tags: c++

I am currently working in Ubuntu Linux. I am working with
a .hpp file and .cpp file. From these two I am 
creating an `.a` file (like a dll in order to use and work with 
my application on any computer that has linux installed).

I mention the fact that both .hpp and.cpp are in folder 1.

I would like to ask :

1. If I include in .cpp a header from a folder like:
   `#include "/home/tests/folder1/folder2/header.h"`
   will this work correctly after i create the .a using ar rcs and send my .a on another computer?
2. does the path to a specific header from a folder influence the .a created?
3. If I had to download for example gsoap in order
   to accomplish my task, after I've created 
   the `.a` file that contains a lot of `.xml` and `.cpp`/`.h` files 
   from gsoap and from my `.h` and `.cpp` file do I need 
   to create a makefile in order to download gsoap 
   on the computer where I want to use my `.a` (or dll in windows) 
   application?

Comment: Did any of these answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

"does the path to a specific header from a folder influence the .a created?" - Only may be debug information. Nothing that would prevent it from working if you copy it to another place.

- *.a is a static library. It is like *.lib in windows - not like *.dll
- You can move any static and dynamic libraries (*.a/*.so in linux, *.lib/*.dll in windows) to any folder/computer/planet you like and use it there while dependencies are satisfied (available all the necessary dynamic and static libs, software, hardware that your library depend on). Of course running the code using your library will require the CPU architecture you've compiled for and all dynamic libs your code uses directly or indirectly.
- Not directly related to the question asked: don't #include files by absolute paths. Ever. Define and use include directories. It is a matter of style and readability. Includes like `"/home/user/working_dir/blabla.h"` or `"D:/working_dir/blabla.h"` or `"..\..\some\directory\blabla.h"` is ugly and unmaintainable. Includes like `<blabla.h>` or `<blabla/defs.h>` is perfect for library APIs and like "blabla.h" or "subdir/blabla.h" is OK for internal headers.

Answer (score 1):

1. "Any computer that has linux installed" isn't going to work. Linux encases a wide variety of platforms and architectures, unlike Windows which generally encases only two (and the 64-bit versions are backward compatible with the 32-bit versions, so the .dlls always work).

   As already mentioned elsewhere, a `.a` is a *static library* and is equivalent to a Windows `.lib`, not a `.dll`. The Linux equivalent to a Windows `.dll` is a `.so` "shared object".
2. No. `#include`s are resolved by the pre-processor in a step prior to compilation. The contents of the file are literally inserted into the copy of your source file in memory, then the whole lot is compiled. The string with the folder does *not* exist in your actual compiled module.
   That said, *writing absolute paths is very bad form*. It means you cannot move your development environment/directory anywhere. Use relative paths: they should be relative to your current working directory and/or to your defined include path. Read your toolchain's documentation for more information.
3. If you statically link `gsoap`, then you don't have to do anything. It's compiled into your project.
   If you want to dynamically link it, then your `.a` should not contain any `.cpp` files from `gsoap`. The target computer must have `gsoap` shared libraries installed, and this will be a required dependency that your installer or your user must resolve.
   Makefiles do not download dependencies. Package managers do.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, a ".a" file is an archive file.  Linux chose that format for its library files, so you can compare it to ".lib" (".so" is the rough equivalent of ".dll").

There are a number of stages of compilation: preprocessing, compiling, assembling and linking.

Preprocessing effectively answers your first question because code in the .h/.hpp file is inserted into the .cpp file, meaning that when your code is compiled, all code that is necessary to compile the .cpp file successfully is in that one file.

Compiling turns your code into assembly instructions for the specific computer that you're using.  This means that if your code was built to run on a PowerPC computer (Mac), your code would use machine instructions that any PPC computer could use (meaning that Intel, AMD, SPARC, Alpha, etc. computers couldn't use your code).  This answers your question about moving a ".a" file to another computer - you can use it as long as the computer's processor AND operating system is compatible (you may have a 64-bit processor, but that doesn't mean 32-bit Windows will let you use it to its full capacity).

Assembling converts the primitive text-based assembly instructions into machine instructions that the processor can understand.  This creates an object file (.obj on Windows, .o on Linux).  This file is what goes in the library (.lib on Windows, .a on Linux).  There are other names for machine instructions such as "machine code" and "object code", and any one of them can be used to describe the same thing.

Linking is the last stage.  It takes the necessary code from libraries and the various necessary object files and turns them into an actual binary (.exe file on Windows, Linux doesn't need an extension because of how it is designed).  This is your application.

Because linking is the last stage, the gsoap library (for example) must be specified in addition to your library or else the linker will say it couldn't find certain "symbols".  However, as with your library, the gsoap library must be on that computer to be able to use it.  Installing it with the package manager is preferred when possible, but if you can't do that, you need to compile it on that computer.  If you're moving from a PPC computer to an Intel/AMD computer, you would also need to re-compile your library as well as gsoap (if you couldn't install gsoap via package manager).